# Body classes still showing 'page-node-#' instead of title or menu word

Tags: theming

I'm trying to get either the title of a page or the menu entry to be listed as a class in the body tag. I came across a posting here utilizing this code:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias();
  $aliases = explode('/', $path);

  foreach($aliases as $alias) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = drupal_clean_css_identifier($alias);
  } 
}
```

flushed all caches but my body tag still looks like:

```
<body class="html not-front not-logged-in no-sidebars page-node page-node- page-node-47 node-type-page section-content">
```

So instead of that page-node-47, I'd like to see 'about-us' or whatever the path or title of the page is. I guess the path would be a better option for a class name but I'm not picky on that matter right now.

I do have Pathauto and clean urls installed and working. And in my html.tpl, I do have this:

```
<body class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes;?>>
```

Comment: Is your theme based on Omega? If not, have you checked that `$path` and `$aliases` contain what you expect? The code you've got wouldn't remove the `page-node-#` class (in case you were hoping it does), it should, in theory, just add a bunch of new classes

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your function is named THEMENAME_preprocess_html(). If you don't have THEMENAME replaced with the name of your theme, the function won't be called and your classes won't get added.

Answer (score 0):

@Richard yes, I have my theme name, neptune instead of "THEMENAME" and so, no @Clive I'm not using Omega but a child theme of Neptune.

so to check the $path and $aliases, do I just print those vars in the template.php (and then remove) as the correct way to get the values?